# Microsoft SQL Server 2000 file records not in standard unicode, but made with Borland C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, unicode, c++builder

I am recently trying to change our company's old program. One of the huge rocks in my way is that the old program was made with Borland C++, and it had its own way of connecting to the SQL Server 2000 database.

After 8 years, I'm trying to retire this program. But when I looked at the database, I got freaked out!

The whole database was in a vague language that was supposed to be Persian.

I'll give you a portion of the database converted to SQL Server 2005, so you can see it for yourself. I've spent many days trying to figure out how to decode this data. But so far no results has come out of  it.

[Link to the sample Database File](http://clickasun.ir/clickasun/SalesDB.rar)

So please if you can tell me how to use them in Microsoft C#.net it will be much appreciated.

These are the datatypes used for them:
[image]

And this is how it looks:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `varchar` datatype used in your column definition is **NOT** Unicode capable... you need to use `nvarchar(256)` instead! Also: instead of `char(100)` (for surname) I'd **strongly** recommend using `nvarchar(100)` - don't use the fixed-width `char(x)` for such a long string!

Comment: So far as there was no Direct answer I tried working on it myself and eventually I came up with an unexpected answer.
Looks like **Borland does not understand unicode in data base, so it just fills the database and later as you set your system Locale, it shows the data in that Locale**. Stupid ha???
any way I had to make a program to replace any character with its persian one and now it is all fixed up. hope it will be helpfull to ya.

By the way I want to thank dda & devio for their assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Analyse existing program and original database

Try to figure out how the C++ program stored Persian text in the database. What are the collations defined on the original server, database, and on column level.

Does the C++ program convert the data to be stored and retrieved from the database? If so, find out how.

It may well be that the program displays data in Persian, but does not store it in a compatible way. Or it uses a custom font that supports custom encoding. All this needs to be analyzed.

2) The screen shots looks as if everything Persian is encoded as ASCII characters higher than CHAR(128).

If this a standardized encoding or custom created?

3) To migrate the database, you most likely will need to convert the data mapping original characters to Unicode characters.

First recreate the tables using Unicode-enabled columns (NVARCHAR, NVARCHAR(MAX)) rather than CHAR and VARCHAR, which only support Latin or Extended Latin.

4) Even if you successfully migrated your data, SSMS may not correctly display the stored data due to font settings or OS support.

I summarized the difficulties of displaying Unicode in SSMS on [my blog](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/why-cant-i-storedisplay-insert-name-language-data-in-sql-server/).

But first, you need to investigate the original database and application.